# Is there low level documentation about creating transactions available?

Tags: rpc, api, documentation

I am fairly new to tezos but not the ecosystem of crypto currencies.
I am trying to develop some sort of C/C++ library, that is capable of creating a tezos transaction, constructing stake and unstake commands and sign these externally.

I was not able to find any official documentation on how these commands are constructed. Is there any documentation available on what is part of a transaction? In what format is it sent to the tezos-node. And what RPC call do I need to do so?

Can anybody help or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation on serialization here: https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/p2p.html

And a usefull implementation from the Airgap Team at: https://github.com/airgap-it/airgap-coin-lib/tree/master/src/protocols/tezos

RPC call for Injection (<=> publishing) is:
POST
node_url/injection/operation
with Body:
"rax_transaction_bytes_as_hex_string"

Comment: I already hab a look at both of the links when searching for some information. Unfortunately that is no useful documentation. I see lots of fields in the first link with no description at all. And reverse engeneering some other library is not really reliable. So the question is still: Is there any documentation about the construction of those messages, message types, and so on.